# Where to set "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" (lighttpd)

Tags: php, lighttpd, fastcgi

I want to setup the max requests to keep my system RAM from filling up when there is a memory leak.

But I dont know where it is.

Answer (score 3):

/etc/lighttpd/mod_fastcgi.conf:

```
  fastcgi.server = ( ".php" =>
      (( "socket" => "/tmp/php-fastcgi.socket",
          "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
          "max-procs" => 10,
          "bin-environment" => (
              "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "16",
              "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "1000" 
          ),
          "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable" 
      ))
  )
```

It works fine for me.

[Lighttpd - Docs:PerformanceFastCGI - lighty labs](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs:PerformanceFastCGI#Can-I-have-too-many-PHP-processes)

Comment: It's also recommended that you set PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS to 500 or so in the very next part of the FAQ.